# Is it possible to extract logic that depends on the Environment outside of the struct that uses it?

Tags: swiftui, environment

Is it possible to extract logic that depends on the SwiftUI environment outside of the views?

For example, consider the scenario where you have a `Theme` struct that computes a color depending on a property in the environment, something akin to the sample code below.

What I'd like to do is extract out the logic that computes a color so that it can be used in multiple places. Ideally I'd like to use `@Environment` in the `Theme` struct so that I only have to retrieve the value it in once place - the alternative is that I retrieve from the environment at the call site of my Theme computation and inject the value in. That alternative works fine, but I'd like to avoid the need to retrieve the environment value all over the place.

```swift
/// A structure to encapsulate common logic, but the logic depends on values in the environment.
struct Theme {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool
        
    var color: Color {
        isEnabled ? .blue : .gray
    }
}

/// One of many views that require the logic above
struct MyView: View {

    let theme: Theme
        
    var body: some View {
        theme.color
    }
}

/// A little app to simulate the environment values changing
struct MyApp: App {

    @State var disabled: Bool
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Toggle("Disabled", isOn: $disabled)
                 MyView(theme: Theme())
                    .disabled(disabled)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Sample code above **doesn't** work, ie if you toggle the switch in the app the View's color does not change. This sample code only serves to show how I'd ideally like it to work, particularly because it doesn't require me to litter `@Environment` throughout `MyView` and similar views just to retrieve the value and pass it into a shared function.

One thing that I thought could be causing the problem is that the `Theme` is created outside of the scope where the Environment is changing, but if I construct a `Theme` inside `MyView` the behaviour doesn't change.

My confusion here indicates that I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding of the SwiftUI Environment. I'd love to understand *why* that sample code doesn't work. If `Theme` were a `View` with the `color` logic in its `body`, it would be updating, so why doesn't it cause an update in it's current setup?

Comment: Sometimes it works but it won’t reliably, SwiftUI wrappers depend on the body of a SwiftUI view look at the dynamic property info

Comment: This code won't compile because `disabled` isn't a variable on `MyApp`

Comment: It's not updating because `@Environment` is meant to be injected into `View`s. You can't inject it to a random struct.

Comment: @Timmy, actually can, because it is just a wrapper (language feature), but it will not work, because it is updated (by corresponding modifier) only being declared inside views.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be different, view parts in views, model parts in models, "separate and rule"

```
struct Theme {    // << view layer independent !!

    func color(for enabled: Bool) -> Color { // << dependency injection !!
        enabled ? .blue : .gray
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool

    let theme: Theme
        
    var body: some View {
        theme.color(for: isEnabled)    // << here !!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're mixing a few things, so let me tell you how I'd structure this.

First of all, I don't think a theme should have state, it should be a repository of colors.

```
struct Theme {
    var enabledColor: Color = .blue
    var disabledColor: Color = .gray
}
```

Your `View` is where you should have your state

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool
        
    var body: some View {
        // ??
    }
}
```

What I would suggest is that you create your own `EnvironmentKey` and inject your theme into the environment:

```
struct ThemeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Theme = .init()
}
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var theme: Theme {
        get { self[ThemeKey.self] }
        set { self[ThemeKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Now your `View` can use the environment to read the theme. I like to keep my views light of logic, but presentation logic in them makes sense to me.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.theme) var theme
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var isEnabled: Bool
        
    var body: some View {
        isEnabled ? theme.enabledColor : theme.disabledColor
    }
}
```

You'll need to inject your theme at some point in your app, you should add it near the top of the view hierarchy to make sure all views get access to it.

```
struct MyApp: App {

    @State var disabled: Bool
    @State var theme: Theme = .init()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Toggle("Disabled", isOn: $disabled)
                 MyView()
                    .disabled(disabled)
            }
            .environment(\.theme, theme)
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote [this article about using the environment to provide values to the view hierarchy](https://betterprogramming.pub/environment-values-as-an-alternative-to-dependency-injection-in-swiftui-a9de89854afe), you may find it useful.